# How does foldLeft in Scala work on DataFrame?

Tags: scala

I had a requirement to ingest an RDBMS table into Hive and I had to clean the data in its String columns, before inserting it into a Hive table using a regex_replace pattern. After failing to understand how to apply it on my dataFrame, I finally I came across a method in Scala which is `foldLeft` which helped in fulfilling the requirement.

I understand how foldLeft works on a collection, for example:

```
List(1,3,9).foldLeft(100)((x,y) => x+y)
```

foldLeft takes arguments: initialValue and a function. It adds the result of the function to the accumulator. In the above case, the result is: 113.

But when it comes to dataframe, I am unable to understand how it works.

```
val stringColumns = yearDF.schema.fields.filter(_.dataType == StringType).map(_.name)
val finalDF = stringColumns.foldLeft(yearDF){ (tempdf, colName) => tempdf.withColumn(colName, regexp_replace(col(colName), "\n", "")) }
```

In the above code, I got the String columns from the dataFrame: `yearDF` which is kept in the accumulator of the `foldLeft`. I have the following doubts regarding the function used in `foldLeft`:

1. What value does tempDF hold ? If it is the same as yearDF, how is it mapped to yearDF ?
2. If `withColumns` is used in the function and the result is added to
   yearDF, how come it is not creating duplicating columns when

Could anyone explain it, so that I can have a better understanding about foldLeft.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Consider a trivialized `foldLeft` example more similar to your DataFrame version:

```
List(3, 2, 1).foldLeft("abcde")((acc, x) => acc.take(x))
```

If you look closely at what the `(acc, x) => acc.take(x)` function does in each iteration, the `foldLeft` is no difference from the following:

```
"abcde".take(3).take(2).take(1)
// Result: "a"
```

Going back to the `foldLeft` for your DataFrame:

```
stringColumns.foldLeft(yearDF){ (tempdf, colName) =>
  tempdf.withColumn(colName, regexp_replace(col(colName), "\n", ""))
}
```

Similarly it's no difference from:

```
val sz = stringColumns.size

yearDF.
  withColumn(stringColumns(0), regexp_replace(col(stringColumns(0)), "\n", "")).
  withColumn(stringColumns(1), regexp_replace(col(stringColumns(1)), "\n", "")).
  ...
  withColumn(stringColumns(sz - 1), regexp_replace(col(stringColumns(sz - 1)), "\n", ""))
```

> 1. What value does tempDF hold ? If it is the same as yearDF, how is it mapped to yearDF ?

In each iteration (i = 0, 1, 2, ...), `tempDF` holds a new DataFrame transformed from applying `withColumn(stringColumns(i), ...)`, starting from `yearDF`

> 2. If withColumns is used in the function and the result is added to yearDF, how come it is not creating duplicating columns when

From `withColumn(stringColumns(i), regexp_replace(col(stringColumns(i)), "\n", ""))`, method `withColumn` creates a new DataFrame, "adding" a column with the same name as the column `stringColumns(i)` it derives from, thus essentially resulting in a new DataFrame with the same column list as the original `yearDF`.

Comment: Awesome explanation.

Comment: https://manuzhang.github.io/2018/07/11/spark-catalyst-cost.html

Comment: @Leo C Could you please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63775189/select-and-withcolumn-both-are-not-working-with-foldleft). Can we apply multiple clauses on `foldleft`

Answer (score 0):

Just to make one point clearer about your second question.
When you call `dataframe.withColumn()` with an existing column name, it returns a new dataframe with the original column replaced with the new column.

This happens regardless to whether you're in the context of a foldLeft operation.