# Advice on refactoring Scala - can I eliminate vars that are being used in foreach loops

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Looking for some advice on how I can refactor some Scala code to make it more elegant, more idiomatic Scala.

I have a function

```
def joinDataFramesOnColumns(joinColumns: Seq[String]) : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

that operates upon a `Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame]` by joining them together on `joinColumns`. Here is the function definition:

```scala
implicit class SequenceOfDataFrames(dataFrames: Seq[DataFrame]){
    def joinDataFramesOnColumns(joinColumns: Seq[String]) : DataFrame = {
      val emptyDataFrame = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate().emptyDataFrame
      val nonEmptyDataFrames = dataFrames.filter(_ != emptyDataFrame)
      if (nonEmptyDataFrames.isEmpty){
        emptyDataFrame
      }
      else {
        if (joinColumns.isEmpty) {
          return nonEmptyDataFrames.reduce(_.crossJoin(_))
        }
      nonEmptyDataFrames.reduce(_.join(_, joinColumns))
    }
  }
}
```

I've got some unit tests that all succeed:

```scala
class FeatureGeneratorDataFrameExtensionsTest extends WordSpec {
  val fruitValues = Seq(
    Row(0, "BasketA", "Bananas", "Jack"),
    Row(2, "BasketB", "Oranges", "Jack"),
    Row(2, "BasketC", "Oranges", "Jill"),
    Row(3, "BasketD", "Oranges", "Jack"),
    Row(4, "BasketE", "Oranges", "Jack"),
    Row(4, "BasketE", "Apples", "Jack"),
    Row(4, "BasketF", "Bananas", "Jill")
  )
  val schema = List(
    StructField("weeksPrior", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("basket", StringType, true),
    StructField("Product", StringType, true),
    StructField("Customer", StringType, true)
  )
  val fruitDf = spark.createDataFrame(
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(fruitValues),
    StructType(schema)
  ).withColumn("Date", udfDateSubWeeks(lit(dayPriorToAsAt), col("weeksPrior")))

  "FeatureGenerator.SequenceOfDataFrames" should {
    "join multiple dataframes on a specified set of columns" in {
      val sequenceOfDataFrames = Seq[DataFrame](
        fruitDf.withColumnRenamed("weeksPrior", "weeksPrior1"),
        fruitDf.withColumnRenamed("weeksPrior", "weeksPrior2"),
        fruitDf.withColumnRenamed("weeksPrior", "weeksPrior3"),
        fruitDf.withColumnRenamed("weeksPrior", "weeksPrior4"),
        fruitDf.withColumnRenamed("weeksPrior", "weeksPrior5")
      )
      val joinedDataFrames = sequenceOfDataFrames.joinDataFramesOnColumns(Seq("basket", "Product", "Customer", "Date"))
      assert(joinedDataFrames.columns.length === 9)
      assert(joinedDataFrames.columns.contains("basket"))
      assert(joinedDataFrames.columns.contains("Product"))
      assert(joinedDataFrames.columns.contains("Customer"))
      assert(joinedDataFrames.columns.contains("Date"))
      assert(joinedDataFrames.columns.contains("weeksPrior1"))
      assert(joinedDataFrames.columns.contains("weeksPrior2"))
      assert(joinedDataFrames.columns.contains("weeksPrior3"))
      assert(joinedDataFrames.columns.contains("weeksPrior4"))
      assert(joinedDataFrames.columns.contains("weeksPrior5"))
    }
    "when passed a list of one dataframe return that same dataframe" in {
      val sequenceOfDataFrames = Seq[DataFrame](fruitDf)
      val joinedDataFrame = sequenceOfDataFrames.joinDataFramesOnColumns(Seq("basket", "Product"))
      assert(joinedDataFrame.columns.sorted === fruitDf.columns.sorted)
      assert(joinedDataFrame.count === fruitDf.count)
    }
    "when passed an empty list of dataframes return an empty dataframe" in {
      val joinedDataFrame = Seq[DataFrame]().joinDataFramesOnColumns(Seq("basket"))
      assert(joinedDataFrame === spark.emptyDataFrame)
    }
    "when passed an empty list of joinColumns return the dataframes crossjoined" in {
      val sequenceOfDataFrames = Seq[DataFrame](fruitDf,fruitDf, fruitDf)
      val joinedDataFrame = sequenceOfDataFrames.joinDataFramesOnColumns(Seq[String]())
      assert(joinedDataFrame.count === scala.math.pow(fruitDf.count, sequenceOfDataFrames.size))
      assert(joinedDataFrame.columns.size === fruitDf.columns.size * sequenceOfDataFrames.size)
    }
  }
}
```

This was all working great until it started erroring due to this Spark bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25150 which can cause an error under certain conditions when the join columns have the same name.

The workaround is to alias the columns as something else so I rewrote the function like so which aliases the join columns, does the join, then renames them back:

```scala
  implicit class SequenceOfDataFrames(dataFrames: Seq[DataFrame]){
    def joinDataFramesOnColumns(joinColumns: Seq[String]) : DataFrame = {
      val emptyDataFrame = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate().emptyDataFrame
      val nonEmptyDataFrames = dataFrames.filter(_ != emptyDataFrame)
      if (nonEmptyDataFrames.isEmpty){
        emptyDataFrame
      }
      else {
        if (joinColumns.isEmpty) {
          return nonEmptyDataFrames.reduce(_.crossJoin(_))
        }

      /*
      The horrible, gnarly, unelegent code below  would ideally exist simply as:

      nonEmptyDataFrames.reduce(_.join(_, joinColumns))

      however that will fail in certain specific circumstances due to a bug in spark,
      see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25150 for details
       */
      val aliasSuffix = "_aliased"
      val aliasedJoinColumns = joinColumns.map(joinColumn => joinColumn+aliasSuffix)
      var aliasedNonEmptyDataFrames: Seq[DataFrame] = Seq()
      nonEmptyDataFrames.foreach(
        nonEmptyDataFrame =>{
          var tempNonEmptyDataFrame = nonEmptyDataFrame
          joinColumns.foreach(
            joinColumn => {
              tempNonEmptyDataFrame = tempNonEmptyDataFrame.withColumnRenamed(joinColumn, joinColumn+aliasSuffix)
            }
          )
          aliasedNonEmptyDataFrames = aliasedNonEmptyDataFrames :+ tempNonEmptyDataFrame
        }
      )
      var joinedAliasedNonEmptyDataFrames = aliasedNonEmptyDataFrames.reduce(_.join(_, aliasedJoinColumns))
      joinColumns.foreach(
        joinColumn => joinedAliasedNonEmptyDataFrames = joinedAliasedNonEmptyDataFrames.withColumnRenamed(
          joinColumn+aliasSuffix, joinColumn
        )
      )
      joinedAliasedNonEmptyDataFrames
    }
  }
}
```

The tests still pass so I'm fairly happy with it but I'm looking at those `var`s and the loops that assign a result back to that `var` on each iteration ... and find them rather inelegant, rather ugly, especially compared to the original version of the function. I feel that there must be a way to write this so that I don't have to use `var`s, but after some trial and error this is the best I can do.

Can anyone suggest a more elegant solution? As a novice Scala developer it would really help me to become more familiar with idiomatic ways of solving problems like this.

Any constructive comments on the rest of the code (e.g. the tests) would also be welcome

Comment: I think you can use [foldLeft](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.12/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable@foldLeft[B](z:B)(op:(B,A)=%3EB):B) method to replace `var` with `foreach`.

Comment: I have posted an answer based on foldLeft

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you to @Duelist whose suggestion to use foldLeft() led me to [How does foldLeft in Scala work on DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52025223/how-does-foldleft-in-scala-work-on-dataframe) which in turn led me to adapting my code like so to eliminate the `var`s:

```scala
  implicit class SequenceOfDataFrames(dataFrames: Seq[DataFrame]){
    def joinDataFramesOnColumns(joinColumns: Seq[String]) : DataFrame = {
      val emptyDataFrame = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate().emptyDataFrame
      val nonEmptyDataFrames = dataFrames.filter(_ != emptyDataFrame)
      if (nonEmptyDataFrames.isEmpty){
        emptyDataFrame
      }
      else {
        if (joinColumns.isEmpty) {
          return nonEmptyDataFrames.reduce(_.crossJoin(_))
        }

        /*
        The code below  would ideally exist simply as:

        nonEmptyDataFrames.reduce(_.join(_, joinColumns))

        however that will fail in certain specific circumstances due to a bug in spark,
        see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25150 for details

        hence this code aliases the joinColumns, performs the join, then renames the 
        aliased columns back to their original name
         */
        val aliasSuffix = "_aliased"
        val aliasedJoinColumns = joinColumns.map(joinColumn => joinColumn+aliasSuffix)
        val joinedAliasedNonEmptyDataFrames = nonEmptyDataFrames.foldLeft(Seq[DataFrame]()){
          (tempDf, nonEmptyDataFrame) => tempDf :+ joinColumns.foldLeft(nonEmptyDataFrame){
            (tempDf2, joinColumn) => tempDf2.withColumnRenamed(joinColumn, joinColumn+aliasSuffix)
          }
        }.reduce(_.join(_, aliasedJoinColumns))
        joinColumns.foldLeft(joinedAliasedNonEmptyDataFrames){
          (tempDf, joinColumn) => tempDf.withColumnRenamed(joinColumn+aliasSuffix, joinColumn)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I could have taken it further by combining two statements into one and thus eliminating `val joinedAliasedNonEmptyDataFrames` but I preferred the clarity brought by using that interim `val`.